# put shadow on window extjs

Tags: extjs

I want to put shadow on this window, I tried a lot of variants, but nothing.

```
var win;
var button;  

function wind(cerand) {

    button = Ext.get('show-btn' + cerand);

    if(!win) {
        win = new Ext.Window({
            applyTo: 'hello-win' + cerand,
            layout: 'fit',

            closeAction: 'hide',
            plain: true,
            html: 'hello-win' + cerand,
            width: '400',
            height: '300',
            items: new Ext.FormPanel({
                applyTo: 'hello-tabs' + cerand
            }),

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                handler: function() {
                    win.hide();
                }
            }]
        });
    }
    win.alignTo(document, 'c-c', [0, -10]);
    win.show(button);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ext.Window instances are automatically given shadows by default, though the effect is subtle. You can control limited aspects of the shadow with the 'shadow' and 'shadowOffset' configuration options.

```
new Ext.Window({
    shadow: 'drop',
    shadowOffset: 10
});
```

More information on these options can be found in the API documentation for Ext.Window and Ext.Shadow:

- http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Window
- http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Shadow

Answer (score 0):

Owlness is right.

```
shadow: 'drop'
```

Will give you a shadow on a floating panel (or window). I personally found that I didn't like the shadow which was produced. It was grey rather than transparent black. You can override this (or anything else about the shadow) in css like so:

```
.x-css-shadow[style] {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 25px !important;
}
```

On IE 8 and earlier this will fall-back in the same way ext's implementation does. But [most browsers support box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)